# Are all cookies created equal?

Tags: php, python, cookies, web, authentication

I'm busy creating a login system to the admin area of my new personal website. The site backend is written entirely in Python, owing to my knowledge of the language.

I have been looking at ways of tracking a user once they login so that the rest of the site knows they are logged in.

I can't get a definitive answer online (unless I'm not looking hard enough or are searching the wrong thing) as to whether are all cookies are the same and accessible from all languages. My tests have proved inconclusive; either they are not or I am doing it wrong but some clarification would be appreciated.

For example, if I create a cookie in Python with cookie.SimpleCookie() in the http.cookies module, is there a way of loading and accessing the value of this cookie in PHP?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Ilmiont

Comment: cookies are available via any language so long as they are for the same domain

Comment: @taryn-east - you should make your comment an answer if you can - especially if you can include code snippets.

Comment: I know that I can't provide enough information for it to count as a proper answer... thus why I provided it as commentary only (I've spent too long hitting the review queues to write a partial answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookie are just cookies and browsers don't record (and possibly can't) how they were created. So when you create one cookie using PHP and then you would like to read the same cookie using any other language that support cookie, you should do it without a problem.

Of course you need to remember about cookie domain and path. They should be set properly if you want to access your cookie without a problem.

Comment: Thanks very much... Could save me a lot of time.